# DropCreateDatabaseAlways Seed not called

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm having an issue getting the Seed method to be called on my custom Database initializer. I'm using EF 5.0 and have the following code:

```
public static class MyDatabase
{
    public static void Initialize()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new MyInitializer());
    }
}

public class MyInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<MyContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(MyContext context)
    {
        base.Seed(context);
        context.Roles.Add(new Role
        {
            ID = 1,
            Name = "User",
        });
        context.Roles.Add(new Role
        {
            ID = 2,
            Name = "Admin",
        });
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

These two classes exist in a separate class library from the MVC app. In the `Global.asax`, I call the `Initialize()` method:

```
MyDatabase.Initialize();
```

The database gets created just fine, it's just the `Seed(MyContext context)` method isn't called and no data gets put into my database.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what happens if you put base.Seed at the end of the method?

Comment: Same thing, it isn't called. I put a breakpoint on the context.Roles.Add and it never breaks. Would it have anything to do with the initializer being in a different class library and not in the web project itself? I thought I've done it this way before, but can't remember specifically.

Comment: It could. It could also be that you've put everything in a static class.

Answer (score 13):

Your  database  will be created later on when you use your context or
You could always force it to create by using your context in the Application_Start() method in Global.asax.cs like:

```
  System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer(new MyInitializer());
MyContext db = new MyContext();
db.Database.Initialize(true);
```

Comment: I have not had a chance to try this out yet, but when I do I'll let you know how it goes. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 3):

In my situation, Seed was not called because I had enabled migrations. When I removed migrations it worked. http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/1689

Answer (score 1):

The `Seed` method will be called once you send the first SQL query to your database, not in your `Application_Start`. For example:

```
using (var ctx = new MyContext())
{
    var rolesCount = ctx.Roles.Count(); // should return 2
}
```

Comment: I am sending queries to the database. This I can confirm using Intellitrace. In the layout, I'm populating a dropdown with a list of data that always comes up empty. I'm also attempting to save a user to a role that doesn't exist.